# Django-cms: Can't publish 2 pages with the same slug in different levels

Tags: python, django, django-cms, slug

I'm having an issue with slugs in child pages. Imagine I have a page called "Something" in the main tree with the slug "something", and another page named "Anything" with the slug "anything". This second page (Anything) has a child page also called "Something" with the slug "something" again, that should result in an /anything/something/ url, and it was working on django-cms 2.3.5 but it's not working anymore on 2.4.1, i get an error saying i've already used that url (Page 'Something' has the same url 'something' as current page "Something"). It's the only thing stoping me from updating to 2.4.1 (latest release in the moment). Thank you. Note that It will let me create the duplicate page if its not published. The problem is when I try to publish them.

Comment: It should work. I try it with a new setup django cms and slugs are not unique so you can use it twice and more.
I think something in your db is wrong

Comment: I was trying around and I got this error too.
It's happen if you save the child before this root page then get the path wrong saved in the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try to delete the pages and readd the pages after it.
2. Start to publish from the root and then the child.

If it still failed, you can check the db table cms_titles. To fix your paths manually or post it here

Comment: Thanks for replying! I created a new database (empty). I'm facing another issue now. When I try to publish a page (root page) by clicking on the check-box inside the page list, it pops up a Javascript alert error with an "undefined" string.

Comment: Hmm, it's a bit of low information to help. Maybe you can collect all information what you have in a new question.

Comment: I got it thanks. It makes much sense to post another question. I've reproduced the steps you mentioned above and it worked. Once more thanks for replying.

Comment: That's behavouir sounds weird. You should check the developer tools of your browser if you can get more information, that you can provide. Looks like that it is an edge case or something is not properly setup.